# How to create my own cli using typescript and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, command-line-interface

I want to create my own cli using typescript and node.

After building the code using `tsc`, I installed as a global cli using `npm install -g .`
When running `test-cli` on cmd, it is expected to print `"test"` on console, but instead it opens a javascript file `build/index.js` on the editor. It seems it opens a file instead of running the file.

While checking the `test-cli.cmd` file in `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm`, I found that it is a bit different from other successful cli files.

`test-cli.cmd` content (not working):

```
...
"%dp0%\node_modules\test-cli\build\index.js"   %*
...
```

`truffle.cmd` content (working correctly):

```
...
IF EXIST "%dp0%\node.exe" (
  SET "_prog=%dp0%\node.exe"
) ELSE (
  SET "_prog=node"
  SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
)

"%_prog%"  "%dp0%\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js" %*
...
```

Definitely having a difference for specifiying `node.exe` to run that javascript file.
How can I fix this problem?

**Here's my code overview**:

Source tree:

```
|__build
|  |__index.js
|  |__index.map.js
|__src
|  |__index.ts
|__package.json
|__tsconfig.json
```

`index.ts` just having a simple code.

```
// index.ts
console.log("my test cli");
```

Also have a simple data in package.json

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "test-cli",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "bin": {
    "test-cli": "build/index.js"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.22",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if that can help, but you could try and use packages like [enquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enquirer) and [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer):

Example:

```js
const { prompt } = require('enquirer');
 
const response = await prompt({
  type: 'input',
  name: 'username',
  message: 'What is your username?'
});
 
console.log(response); // { username: 'jonschlinkert' }
```